# Facebook iOS SDK - Custom Login Design

Tags: facebook, authentication

I figured out that it is impossible to use a custom facebook login since facebook is using a WebView (hope this is true - or can I use two textfields with a button?).

But I really need to change the design of that in-app login screen. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, it's just using the OAuth2 protocol. But you'll have to roll your own (a lot of work). This site has lots of insights on how you might achieve that.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is a good idea because users are used to using Facebook's standard login screen.  But if you wanted your own custom login screen, the only way I think you could do this is via scraping (in violation of Facebook terms of service).